# Retrieving NSDictionary Objects

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

I have this following Dictionary which is extracted from XML Parser. Used the github library to parse the XML file from this following link.

[XML to NSDictionary Parser Library](https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name/XML-to-NSDictionary)

```
 Quiz = { 
questions = (
    {
    "@id" = 1;
    answer = D;
    A = "Under the rock";
    B = "Trees";
    C = "Mountain";
    D = Water;
    question = "Where does the fish live?";
    },
    {
    "@id" = 2;
    answer = D;
    A = "Four";
    B = "Two";
    C = "Six";
    D = Three;
    question = "How many legs for a rabbit?";
    },......
    };
```

I'm trying to retrieve the objects of the key question, answer, option 1-4. But some how I can't go pass the value.

```
for (NSString * key in xmlDictionary) {
        NSDictionary * subDict = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"questions"];
        NSLog(@"Correct Answers \n\n%@", [subDict objectForKey:@"answer"]);
        // all your other code here.
    }
```

The don't think any value is returning. Actually I have 10 elements inside that xml and during the parsing it shows that I have 10 count. However when I try to count the xmlDictionary and it returns 1. Not sure what is going wrong in here?

Also how will I extract all the values depends on the @id?

Confused!!!

Updated: I changed the ... Tags to ... in the XML file

```
NSDictionary *currentObject;
    if (rowIndex < countXML)
    {
        currentObject=[muteArr objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"simple" sender:self];
    }

    NSString *questionLbl = [currentObject objectForKey:@"question"];
    NSString *op1Lbl = [currentObject objectForKey:@"A"];
    NSString *op2Lbl = [currentObject objectForKey:@"B"];
    NSString *op3Lbl = [currentObject objectForKey:@"C"];
    NSString *op4Lbl = [currentObject objectForKey:@"D"];
    NSString *answer = [currentObject objectForKey:@"answer"];
    NSString *questNoLbl = [currentObject objectForKey:@"@ID"];

questionID.text = [@"Question # " stringByAppendingString:questNoLbl];
    question.text = questionLbl;

    [answer1 setTitle:op1Lbl forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answer2 setTitle:op2Lbl forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answer3 setTitle:op3Lbl forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answer4 setTitle:op4Lbl forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now I have this code with the way to retrieve each question and display it in the QuizViewController. When the user the pressed the button it should Segue to a new Controller and display whether the answer is correct or not and returns back to the QuizViewController after clicking the "Continue" button in the ResultViewController. Now I have all these setup.

Now wanted to display whether the answer is correct or not in the ResultViewController.

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
NSDictionary * subDict = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"questions"];
```

you getting the same dictionary back, you already have.

Try this:

```
for (NSString * key in xmlDictionary) {
    NSDictionary * subDict = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"Correct Answers \n\n%@", [subDict objectForKey:@"answer"]);
    // all your other code here.
}
```

With your edited XML structure you should do this:

```
NSDictionary * rootDict = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"questions"];
for (NSString * key in rootDict) {
        NSDictionary * subDict = [rootDict objectForKey:key];
        NSLog(@"Correct Answers \n\n%@", [subDict objectForKey:@"answer"]);
        // all your other code here.
    }
```

Comment: Well I get (null)? Also don't understand why it returns 1 for the "questions". I suspect it is returning 1 coz the the "questions" inside "Quiz". Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: So my dictionary structure is like Quiz { questions ( { data 1 }, {data 2}, ... ) }; So I wanted to extract all the data values with respect to my dictionary shown above.

Comment: Just edited my answer. First you need to get the questions dictionary and then you can iterate trough it.

Comment: Well I just tried it and seems to be that I'm still getting NULL. The loop is not even executing. If I try to print this "NSLog(@"This is where you will get %@", rootDict.description);" It is printing null.

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting the data from the parser right? Seems to me like your dictionary is empty.

Comment: If I print the dictionary.description, I'm getting the dictionary on how I pasted in the above snippet. I truncate the records to put here to show the example. NSLog (xmlDictionary.description) gives the record I have. If you want, I can email you the codes to test and see.

Comment: So the Quiz node is in the xmlDictionary as well? Replace the line: NSDictionary * rootDict = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"questions"]; with this one: NSDictionary * rootDict = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"Quiz.questions"];

Comment: Still it is null brother...
Also I skimmed down to just 1 record in XML and tried a different work around like this and it can read the data. "NSString *nameStr = [[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"Quiz"] objectForKey:@"questions"] objectForKey:@"question"];" If I have more than 1 record then it crashes

Comment: Can you post the xml you're trying to parse? I will take a look at it as soon as I'm at home.

Comment: Not sure how to share here... is there a way to PM you?

Comment: I found a way to retrieve the values and stored them in an array. Now the array has all the values from the XML file. Now how I get data with respect to the ID of each record?

Comment: Please update your question with the whole code from parsing the xml to storing the values in an array.